# Vega: How to display multiple charts in the same view

Tags: vega

I want to display more than one Vega chart in the same view, aligned either horizontally or vertically; i.e., have them grid-like aligned either side by side in the same row or below each other in multiple rows.

Vega-lite supports this directly using the `hconcat` and `vconcat` operator, respectively. But how would you do that in *Vega*? I couldn't find equivalent operators in Vega, but I guess it should be possible in a more low-level way. Any best-practices on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done based on Vega's [*layout*](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/layout) abstraction and [*group marks*](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/group/).

A basic example for a one-column vertical alignment of two charts can be found [here](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/master/packages/vega/test/specs-valid/layout-vconcat.vg.json). Similarly, a one-row horizontal alignment of three charts can be found in [this](https://github.com/vega/vega/blob/master/packages/vega/test/specs-valid/layout-hconcat.vg.json) example.